Getting the UUID of an entries list of a group using pykeepass
I'm looking to get the UUID of the entries of a group with pykeepass.
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pykeepass import PyKeePass

kp = PyKeePass('dbtest.kdbx', password='password')
kpGroup = kp.find_groups(name='GroupTest', first=True)
print(kpGroup.entries)

The code will return this :
[Entry: "GroupTest/test (test@test.com)", Entry: "GroupTest/test (test@test.com)"]

The problem is when 2 entries of the group have a similar Title (test) and username (test@test.com), I am unable to use kp.find_entries() on either the Title or Username, having the uuid displayed by kpGroup.entries for each of those entries will solve the problem.
I would like to have something like this displayed :
[Entry: "GroupTest/test (test@test.com) UUID=uuid", Entry: "GroupTest/test (test@test.com) UUID=uuid"]


It is the difference between

the real content of kpGroup.entries,
the brief info which you get with the print(kpGroup.entries).

So you may obtain arbitrary other info from this list of group entries. You wanted this:
[(e.group, e.title, e.uuid) for e in kpGroup.entries]

You will obtain something as this:

[(Group: "GroupTest", 'test', UUID('dfc7622c-1cc1-f045-84fd-6e6acab78539')),
 (Group: "GroupTest", 'test', UUID('d14a2296-703e-2a40-aa78-f559f6ec090f'))]



Indeed !
for i in kpGroup.entries:
print("Name" + str(i.title), "Uuid" + str(i.uuid))
Work, thanks

@tty0, you're welcome.
